# Login & Registration issue in Joomla 1.6 front end

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

In my client server..I am trying to login there is no response...page only reloading...

And i am trying to register in his site it showing following error

`Invalid Token`

So i am try to print the posted value in registration model page using

`$post = JRequest::get('post');` & `$requestData = JRequest::getVar('jform', array(), 'post', 'array');`

Both variables ($post & $requestData) are return empty....

The same project run successfully in my local server....

Any body face the same problem ?????

Please help me......:(

Comment: check your php versions at both localhost and live server...try this link for joomla 2.5 http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Comment: @swapnesh i tried with `$_POST` its also return empty

Comment: Sorry not joomla 2.5 its joomla 1.6 i am edited my topic

Comment: Client server PHP version : 5.3.10,MySQl : 5.0.92

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your browser has cookies enabled. In case it does, try to delete all your cookies and re-try to login. You can read more about this issue *[here](http://www.itoctopus.com/invalid-token-on-joomla-login)* and *[here](http://techjoomla.com/joomla-development/invalid-token-errors-in-joomla-15x-a-16x.html)*
One more thing, if the above doesn't help, try disabling Joomla's cache (Login module - set to "no cache") and try again to login.

Comment: What about the login problem ?

Comment: This *is* regarding the login problem.

Comment: still saying `Invalid Token`...i changed `no cache` in login module

Comment: Did you delete all the cookies as well ? also, try to totally disable  the cache (from under "global configuration" screen).

Comment: @alfasin..already cache is in disable....and also we removed all cookies and tried..still showing `invalid token` while login & registration..its server problem ?

Answer (score 0):

*** Issue Fixed ***

Follow the steps to fix this issue...

In admin side (Back End)

1,`Site->Maintenance->clear cache`

Remove all pages...

2,Move to `Global configuration`,in `Site` tab,`SEO settings` panel,Set `Use Apache mod_rewrite` as `No` (radio button)